# Two rate chi squared tests infection rate

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, poisson-distribution

We would just like to display a crude statistic to compare infection rate pre/post intervention.  Based on a  paper I read the statistical test I need to apply is a 2 rate chi squared test. I've been looking for a tutorial but haven't been able to find something that I'm looking for.

```
                    MRSA Cases      Patient Days
Pre Intervention       61            102000
Post Intervention      41            110000
```

I have R and can do this in R if that's ideal.

Comment: You'll need to say more for this to be answerable. Are the pre & post numbers on the sample people, eg? Are these hazard rates? What are your data, exactly?

Comment: @gung thanks for your help.  No the data is unit based. So comparing a medical unit pre/post and intervention. http://cid.oxfordjournals.org/content/45/7/901.long This is the paper where I got this information from.

Comment: This is a test for equality of two Poisson means. One would have to hunt down the references to determine more precisely *what* test it is, since there are several (slightly different) ways to formulate such a test.

Answer (score 4):

I gather you have two counts, and which could have been anything (i.e., they are not bounded—counts of successes out of a total number of trials).  The simplest distribution of counts is the [Poisson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution), but there can be other, more complicated, distributions as well (e.g., [negative binomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution)).  With your data, you cannot differentiate between different possible count distributions.  You can *assume* they are Poisson, but that's it, and if that assumption is incorrect, your results will be invalid.

In addition, when people model counts, there is often a variable that indicates some kind of opportunity for an event to occur.  That's what you have as "Patient Days", I gather.  We adjust for this using an [offset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_regression#.22Exposure.22_and_offset).

Thus, it is possible to have a (rather low powered) test of your data by assuming they are realized values from a single Poisson distribution and adjusting with an offset, and seeing if that looks reasonable.  In R, this can be done with the [?poisson.test](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/poisson.test.html) function:

```
poisson.test(x=c(61, 41), T=c(102000, 110000))
# 
#   Comparison of Poisson rates
# 
# data:  c(61, 41) time base: c(102000, 110000)
# count1 = 61, expected count1 = 49.075, p-value = 0.02222
# alternative hypothesis: true rate ratio is not equal to 1
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  1.062580 2.445082
# sample estimates:
# rate ratio 
#   1.604495
```

Comment: Thanks gung appreciate this. We have some preliminary data and we suspect a change has occurred. I think it's time to constult a statistician to go through our data. Really appreciate this.